# Local static/thread_local variables of inline functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

If I have a static local variable or thread_local local variable that is within an inline function that is defined in different translation units, in the final program are they guaranteed by the standard to have the same address?

```
// TU1:
inline int* f() { static int x; return &x; }
extern int* a;
void sa() { a = f(); }

// TU2:
inline int* f() { static int x; return &x; }
extern int* b;
void sb() { b = f(); }

// TU3:
int *a, *b;
void sa();
void sb();
int main() { sa(); sb(); return a == b; }
```

Will the above always return 1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's always the same object. By [dcl.fct.spec]/4:

> An `inline` function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units. A `static` local variable in an `extern inline` function always refers to the same object. A type defined within the body of an `extern inline` function is the same type in every translation unit.

Comment: Thanks, and I guess the `thread_local` case has a similar answer?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: Yes, I think so, because by [dcl.stc]/4, the `thread_local` specifier implies the `static` specifier, and the rule I cited in the answer applies to the *specifier*, not the storage class.

Comment: The quote talks about `extern inline`. Is it the same for `inline` without `extern`?