# Local static variable linkage in a template class static member function

Tags: c++

I have a question similar to [Local static/thread_local variables of inline functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172137/local-static-thread-local-variables-of-inline-functions)

Does the standard guarantee that return value is always 1, meaning that `static int x` is the same across translation units?

```
// TU1
template <int X>
struct C { 
  static int* f() { static int x = X; return &x; }
};

extern int* a1; 
extern int* a2; 
void sa() { a1 = C<1>::f(); a2 = C<2>::f(); }

// TU2
template <int X>
struct C { 
  static int* f() { static int x = X; return &x; }
};

extern int* b1; 
extern int* b2; 
void sb() { b1 = C<1>::f(); b2 = C<2>::f(); }

// TU3
int *a1, *a2, *b1, *b2;
void sa();
void sb();
int main() { sa(); sb(); return a1 == b1 && a2 == b2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the standard guarantee that return value is always 1, meaning that `static int x` is the same across translation units?

The standard *requires* that.

[Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables):

> Function-local static objects in all definitions of the same inline function (which may be implicitly inline) all refer to the same object defined in one translation unit.

---

The compiler generates a copy of that function local static in each translation unit and then the linker picks one and discards the duplicates. When shared libraries are involved they may have their own copies of the object but the runtime linker (`ld.so`) resolves all references to the one that was discovered first. This method is known as [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html):

> Local static variables and string constants used in an inline function are also considered to have vague linkage, since they must be shared between all inlined and out-of-line instances of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it does. We need to examine [[basic.def.odr] ¶6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6)

> There can be more than one definition of a [..] class template,
>   non-static function template, static data member of a class template,
>   member function of a class template, or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not specified ([temp.spec],
>   [temp.class.spec]) in a program provided that each definition appears
>   in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy
>   the following requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in
>   more than one translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and [...]
>
> If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit,
>   then the preceding requirements shall apply both to names from the
>   template's enclosing scope used in the template definition
>   ([temp.nondep]), and also to dependent names at the point of
>   instantiation ([temp.dep]). If the definitions of D satisfy all these
>   requirements, then the behavior is as if there were a single
>   definition of D. If the definitions of D do not satisfy these
>   requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

Your templates are okay in that regard, it's as if they were included from the same header. There are other bullets in that clause that also need to hold, but they are not relevant to your example.

Now, since it's as if there is only one definition of the template and its members in your program, that static variable is *the same variable* in both TU's.